# Challenge: display php array with aggregated result

Tags: php

I am about to bleed with this challenge....anybody can help me with understanding how to solve please. I am missing the logic. I will spare you the details and give you the input variables to work with, which are dynamically generated. The below records are Male, Female, Male, Female....

```
$data=array(1,5,10,4,3,4,1,1,1,'2);
$indexOfSubTotalColumns=array(3,6,9,12,15,18,21);

//This means on the 3, 6th ...column of the HTML output, a summary is to happen. That is 1+5 will be 6 on column 3. 10 +4 will be 14 on column 6.

$groupTotalColumns=array(9,21);

//the 9th column will display sum of all columns before it. and 21 from col 10 on words, excluding the subtotals calculated or if you want.
```

With the following code,I have gotten to calculate the subtotals of each but can't put the dynamic grand total. First, add dumb data to the data array so it becomes equal to the number of HTML columns.

```
$previousValues=array();

foreach($data as $value){

    if(in_array($i,$indexOfSubTotalColumns)){

        $rows.="<td>".array_sum($previousValues)."</td>";
        $rows.="<td>$value</td>";

        $previousValues=array();
        array_push($previousValues,$value);
        $i++;
        // 
    }
    else{//not a subtotal

        $rows.="<td>$value</td>";

        array_push($previousValues,$value);

    }

    $i++;   

    //if $i reaches number of columns i.e. 21, close current row and open new
}

echo $rows;
```

The above code outputs me this layout:

[image]

I am failing to calculate the Totals.

Comment: you array is invalid, array keys must be unique , php will treat you `$data` array as follows: `$data = array('M'=>1,'F'=>2)` and will ignore or overwrite all the previous elements

Comment: Thanks Hassan...lemme edit the post.